# Can I use malloc this way?

Tags: c, sum, malloc, min

I want to find the minimum number and summary from a dynamic integer table. I do not know why results not shown. Have I done something wrong on the malloc ? May I use realloc too ?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i,min,sum,xronos;
    int* array;
    printf("Give me how many numbers does the table will have: \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    array=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("Give the number %d",i);
        printf("\n");
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        sum=sum+array[i];
        if (i=1)
        {
            min=array[i];
        }
        else
        {
            if (array[i]<min)
            {
                min=array[i];
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%d",sum);
    printf("\n The answer is :",(n-2)*min+(sum-min));
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps 'for(i=1;i<=n;i++)' should be 'for(i=0;i<n;i++)' (in both cases)?

Comment: Two things: First [don't cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/440558). Secondly indexing starts at zero and ends at size minus one.

Comment: Also, you should initialize 'sum' to zero?

Comment: Note: Check the return value of `scanf()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>  /* Defines: ENOMEM */

int main()
   {
```

Added rCode to assist in error handling.

```
   int rCode=0;
```

Removed xronos as it is not used.

```
   int n,i,min;
```

Initialized sum to 0;

```
   int sum=0;
```

Initialize array pointer to NULL so cleanup is easier.
       int *array = NULL;

```
   printf("Give me how many numbers does the table will have: \n");
   scanf("%d",&n);
```

There is nothing inherently wrong with casting the output of malloc to (int *).  In some situations, it is a good coding practice.  (good job).

```
   array=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

You should always test that you actually got memory from malloc.

```
   if(NULL == array)
      {
      rCode=ENOMEM;
      fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed.");
      goto CLEANUP;
      }
```

The array element index is in the range of 0 through (n-1).  Start indexing at zero, and be sure to stop at (n-1).

```
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
      printf("Give the number %d",i);
      printf("\n");
      scanf("%d",&array[i]);
      }
```

Again, the array element index is in the range of 0 through (n-1).  Start indexing at zero, and be sure to stop at (n-1).

```
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
      sum=sum+array[i];

      if(1 == i)
         min=array[i];
      else
         {
         if(array[i] < min)
            min=array[i];
         }
      }

   printf("%d",sum);
   printf("\n The answer is :",(n-2)*min+(sum-min));
   getch();

CLEANUP:
```

From my early years, my father would tell me: 'When you bring your toys to the sandbox, always remember to put them away when you are finished.'

```
   if(array)
       free(array);

   return(rCode);
   }
```

Comment: Thank you ! You are very analytical ! I learn many things from your post but I think that the problem isn't solved.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is almost exactly how you are supposed to use `malloc`, except for three small things and one big thing:

- Do not cast `malloc` result in C,
- Use indexes from zero to n-1, inclusive (your code goes from one to n, inclusive)
- Add a call `free(array)` to avoid a memory leak.

The big thing is that you do not need `malloc` in order to solve this problem: you can calculate the `sum` and the `min` as you go, without saving the individual items to an array.

You can replace the chain of `if`s in the loop with this check:

```
if (i == 0 || array[i] < min) {
    min=array[i];
}
```

This covers both the assignment of the first element, and comparison of elements other than the first one.

Finally, you can rewrite this

```
sum=sum+array[i];
```

as

```
sum += array[i];
```

using a composite assignment operator. Don't forget to initialize the `sum` to zero!

Comment: Initializing `min` to some value like `INT_MAX` has the advantage of `min` having a defined value at `printf()` time should `n <= 0`.

Comment: @chux The problem with that is that when `n` is zero or less, `min` is really undefined. There needs to be a check upfront that exits early when a negative or zero `n` is entered.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !!! But how can I get the size of the table from the user without using malloc ?

Comment: @user3403697 The same way that you do now - `scanf("%d",&n);` The change that you need to make is to combine the two loops that you have in one, and replace `array[i]` with a temporary `int` variable that you read, use, and discard in the same iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Line 22, need

```
if (i=1)
```

set to

```
if (i==1)
```

Right now you're setting i equal to 1

Comment: You have right,I didn't see that,I correct it but the problem remains.

Comment: I was able with certain numbers, to get the correct sum, but not the lowest number given. So hopefully it's not a code problem, just a logical issue.